# Is there any lore explanation in Forgotten Realms for the change from Infravision to Darkvision?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, vision-and-light

A long time ago, some races and monsters had the [*Infravision*](https://adnd2e.fandom.com/wiki/Infravision) trait, which allowed them to see in the dark the heat traces of living creatures.

This had very interesting aspects. The drow's sign language\$^1\$ used the heat traces left in the air by the hands to convey messages. In order to become totally invisible in the darkness, one had to magically hide their body heat (see the attack to [House DeVir](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/House_DeVir) in the novel [*Homeland*](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Homeland)).

Nowadays, since the 3rd edition has been published, the *Infravision* has been changed into the more manageable [*Darkvision*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Darkvision), that allows to see in shades of gray instead of seeing the heat traces when in darkness.

Is there any *in-world* explanation in the novels, manuals, adventures or in other official sources about how this change occurred in the Forgotten Realms?

---

\$^1\$ It has been adapted to the 3rd edition *Darkvision* trait, as explained in the ***Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting 3rd edition***, see [here](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Drow_language#:%7E:text=Drow%20Sign%20Language%20was%20a,language%27s%20motions%20as%20spell%20conjurations.).

Comment: Tangentially related: [Why do duergar have Sunlight Sensitivity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115059/23547)

Comment: When the game was invented, people understood infravision as an analogue to use if IR equipment that the military was just then bringing into common use.  By the time of 3.x being publisned, low light vision devices (like NVGs) that were not IR based had become commonplace in advanced militaries (and elsewhere in security applications). There is nothing "in universe" that explains this.  WoTC just decided on a tech upgrade.

Comment: See also the visual acuity of a cat, or other nocturnal creature, in the dark.

Comment: Not a lor explanation, but other issues with "infravision" . . . if it's understood to work by detecting heat, that causes all sorts of fiddly issues . . . you shouldn't be able to see a room-temp trap or probably an undead.  But "darkvision" now, that's magic, and it just let's you see in the dark, as described in the rules.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I think that they just see how it was difficult to apply infravision in game, and switched to a B&W version which is simpler to use..

Comment: @Jack As I wrote in the above comment to Korvin, I think they switched because Darvision is simpler to use in game. Moreover, it is not magic.

Comment: You've used the lore tag, which makes me think that you're asking about some kind of in-world explanation that describes the mechanical change that occurred (i.e. duergar going from having infravision to darkvision). Is that correct? Or are you asking about if there are designer commentary on why the change occurred (at current, all answers seem to be speculating on this supposition).

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I used the lore tag since I am searching for a in-world explanation: I was wondering if I was not clear, but the last line of my question seemed to me pretty explanatory. Otherwise, I would have asked something like "is there any explanation from a game designer that justifies this change?" and used the designer-reason tag. Indeed, the lore tag says "For questions about a setting's in-world details or background".

Comment: Ok, that was what I thought, it was just running contrary to the answers you'd received so I wasn't sure if there was some since deleted commentary to justify that.

Comment: Lorewise, recent Drizzt novels still mention seeing body heat.   And time in Menzoberranzan is still tracked by heating up Narbondel once a day and being able to see it cool down over the entire day.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson That's interesting: which ones?

Comment: The *Homecoming* and *Generations* trilogies both have scenes in Menzoberranzan and the Underdark.  In one, a human disguised as a drow was caught because they did not understand their body heat made them quite visible to races of the Underdark.

Comment: Infravision was a real pain unless you treated it as Darkvision, which was explicitly allowed as an option.  (One DM I suffered under insisted it worked like reallife infrared goggles unless that would have been useful, then it acted as Darkvision.)

Comment: @Mary I know that *Infravision* was very difficult to play: I am not asking why this change has been placed, I am asking if there is some explanation in the world setting.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson I stopped some years ago to read Salvatore's novel, I am not updated: according to a forgottenrealms wiki, these novels take place in around 1487, hence in the current days of 5ed, am I right?

Answer (score 4):

## Vecna blew up the multiverse.

Simply put, the in-universe explanation of the changes between 2e ADnD and 3e DnD was explained by the adventure [*Die Vecna Die!*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Vecna_Die!) by Bruce R. Cordell and Steve Miller.

To quote the adventure itself:

> Even with Vecna's removal, his time in the crux effected change in superspace. Though the Lady of Pain attempts to heal the damage, the turmoil spawned by Vecna's time in Sigil cannot be entirely erased. Some Outer Planes drift off and are forever lost, others collide and merge, while at least one Inner Plane runs "aground" on a distant world of the Prime. Moreover, the very nature of the Prime Material Plane itself is altered. Half-worlds like those attached to Tovag Baragu multiply a millionfold, taking on parallel realism in what was before a unified Prime Material Plane. The concept of alternate dimensions rears its metaphorical head, but doesn't yet solidify, and perhaps it never will. New realms, both near and far, are revealed and realms never previously imagined make themselves known. Entities long thought lost emerge once more, while other creatures, both great and small, are inexplicably eradicated. Some common spells begin to work differently. The changes do not occur immediately, but instead are revealed during the subsequent months. However, one thing remains clear: Nothing will ever be the same again.

The change between infravision and darkvision was part of the 2e to 3e rules updates; it would have been covered under this. In particular, it notes that "some common spells begin to work differently", and this would include the 2e spell *Infravision* and its 3e counterpart *[Darkvision](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/darkvision.htm)*.

Comment: Nothing in that (admittedly awesome) quote mentions infravision, darkvision, or abilities like them. It's definitely _possible_ that a cataclysmic multiverse-shaking event changes how certain creatures' eyes work, but do you have any evidence that supports it?

Comment: @GMJoe It's just a longer version of "a wizard did it" 

Comment: @GMJoe Added a reference to the spells Infravision and Darkvision.

Comment: Although this answer reports interesting information about the switch from 2ed to 3rd ed, I am not asking about the spell but about the racial trait.

Comment: @Eddymage: Sure, but this the only edition switch lore you're likely to find. The whole damn multiverse changed, drastically. All changes from 2E to 3E were caused by Vecna trying to control *everything* and failing. How that caused the changes, nobody can fully explain, but it's the only in-world lore explaining it. For all we know, fixing the damage effectively meant shunting the entire multiverse into a different origin track where infravision had been darkvision from the beginning. They never detailed in-universe reasons for the change beyond this.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast That's hilarious - but there's still no mention of the racial ability anywhere here, making the "a wizard did it" explanation pure speculation with no evidence to back it up.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know that proving a negative is quite difficult, but this does not answer to my question. The only reference to creatures/monster in this post is "while other creatures, both great and small, are inexplicably eradicated", which explains that some type of creatures disappeared, not that their traits have changed in some way. I truly believe that the spells (both *Infravision* and *Darkvision*) were created to mimic the natural trait, not the other way around.

Comment: @GMJoe To be fair, I should have said "a lich did it" rather than "a wizard did it" to be more correct, but apparently he did it accidentally.

Comment: Correllation isn't causation - but more importantly, OP isn't talking about the spell. -1.