# What published resource first introduced the duergar?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, duergar

What published resource first introduced the duergar?

Specifically, I'm interested in when they first given a stat block (if there were allusions to them earlier). I think it was an AD&D module, but don't recall which one; though it is always possible that they were first introduced in Dragon, or an extension rule book etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### *Monster Manual II* (1983)

Duergar first appeared on page 61 of the 1983 *Monster Manual II* for AD&D 1st Edition, at least, this is the earliest publication I am aware of, and some further research has so far yielded no earlier appearances. This is consistent with the research done on duergar for the Forgotten Realms wiki, the earliest citation in [their bibliography](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Duergar#References) is to the 1983 *Monster Manual II*.

Finally, Keith Curtis makes the same assertion in [this stack question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90335/62294), and if it's good enough for Keith, it's good enough for me.

Comment: My recollection is that MM2 includes (if not being primarily comprised of) monsters that first appeared in published modules.

Comment: @Dave See my edit, the earliest reference on Forgotten Realms wiki is the MM2.

Comment: Thomas, I'll go and look at my old AD&D 1e modules to see what I can find about them. I have the idea that one of the Drow / underdark modules had them but I have to check to be sure. *The duergar are an "evil and avaricious" subrace that live in the Underdark*

Comment: @KorvinStarmast D1 through D3 seemed the most promising, but I don’t seem any duergar in those.

Comment: And of course there are/were various dragon magazine article that I may or may not still have ... I could have sworn I saw them before MM II, but it's possible that I am not recalling correctly.