# What published resource first introduced the svirfneblin?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, gnomes

Similar to [What published resource first introduced the duergar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/197828/what-published-resource-first-introduced-the-duergar) I'm curious about when these little deep gnomes first got a stat block.

The earliest I know about them was in Baldur's Gate II (the video game), based in 2e D&D, but I'm sure they're from before then.

Comment: Thank you for not creating a svirfneblin tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### D2 *Shrine of the Kuo-Tua*

The svirfneblin first appeared in the adventure module D2 [*Shrine of the Kuo-Tua*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_into_the_Depths_of_the_Earth), published by TSR in 1978.